# nltk : Replace tokens with other words depending on POS

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on Natural Language Processing and need to pre-process some data. My data is in text file and I have to read the data and change all names to Male or Female.

After reading the data and tokenizing it, I apply pos tagging and check with a file which has list of names and change the name to 'Male' or 'Female'

For example :

> ['Jack', 'and', 'Jill', 'Went', 'up', 'the', 'hill']

should be changed to

> ['Male', 'and', 'Female', 'Went', 'up', 'the', 'hill']

based on the following POS

> [('Jack', 'NNP'),
>    ('and', 'CC'),
>    ('Jill', 'NNP'),
>    ('Went', 'NNP'),
>    ('up', 'IN'),
>    ('the', 'DT'),
>    ('hill', 'NN')]

My code is as follows :

```
import nltk

text = open('collegegirl.txt').read()

with open('male_names.txt') as f1:
    male = nltk.word_tokenize(f1.read())

with open('female_names.txt') as f2:
    female = nltk.word_tokenize(f2.read())  

data = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(text))
for word, pos in data:
    if(pos == 'NNP'):
        if word in male:
            word = 'Male'
        if word in female:
            word = 'Female'
```

The above code is just checking for the words and not writing anything. How do I edit the names in data. I am new to python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: with open('female_names.txt') as f2:
    female = nltk.word_tokenize(f1.read())

should be 

with open('female_names.txt') as f2:
    female = nltk.word_tokenize(**f2**.read())

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. But the code is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the text and do in your `for` loop:

```
for i, (word, pos) in enumerate(data):
    if(pos == 'NNP'):
        if word in male:
            data[i] = ('Male', pos)
        if word in female:
            data[i] = ('Female', pos)
array = [text for (text, pos) in data]
```

The more python way to do it:

```
array = [x if (not pos == "NNP" and not x in male and not x in female) else ("Female" if (x in female) else ( "Male" if (x in male) else x)) for (x, pos) in data]
```

Comment: Not working. Throws the error TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @bkshi I edited my answer, `array` should contain `['Male', 'and', 'Female', 'Went', 'up', 'the', 'hill']`

Comment: Still not working. It is showing `IndexError: list assignment index out of range
`

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, It is better to use Spacy for POS tagging which is fast and more accurate. Also, you can use its named entity recogntion to check whether a word is a PERSON or not. Install spacy and download the `en_core_web_lg` model from here https://spacy.io/usage/

Your problems can be solved as:

```
import spacy
from functools import reduce

nlp_spacy = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

NAMELIST = {'Christiano Ronaldo':'Male', 'Neymar':'Male', 'Messi':'Male', "Sandra":'Female'}

with open("input.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

doc = nlp_spacy(text)

names_in_text = [(entity.text, NAMELIST[entity.text])  for entity in doc.ents if entity.label_ in ['PERSON'] and entity.text in NAMELIST]
print(names_in_text)       #------- prints [('Christiano Ronaldo', 'Male'), ('Messi', 'Male')]

replaced_text = reduce(lambda x, kv: x.replace(*kv), names_in_text, text)
print(replaced_text)       #------- prints Male scored three. Male scored one. Female is an athlete. I am from US.
```